# Где в гугл хром посмотреть значения сохранённые в сессию битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

В битриксе есть сессии

```
$session = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getInstance()->getSession();
if (!$session->has('foo'))
{
    $session->set('foo', 'bar');            
}

echo $session['foo']; //bar
```

Как в гугл хроме посмотреть значение сессии?

Comment: Никак. Вернее написать код на сервере, но это не имеет никакого отношения к хрому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак

Из **php.net**, `\Bitrix\Main\Application::getInstance()->getSession()` является оберткой над `$_SESSION`:

> Сессии являются простым способом хранения информации для отдельных пользователей с уникальным идентификатором сессии. Это может использоваться для сохранения состояния между запросами страниц. Идентификаторы сессий обычно отправляются браузеру через сессионный cookie и используются для получения имеющихся данных сессии. Отсутствие идентификатора сессии или сессионного cookie сообщает PHP о том, что необходимо создать новую сессию и сгенерировать новый идентификатор сессии.